# Conversion of summation to integration

Tags: fourier-transform

Generally when we write 
$ f=\int ydx$  we are calculating the area of the curve represented by the function y . So how can we calculate the sum of a set of functions such as
 $$f(z)=\sum_i {A(k_i)e^{(k_i z-wt)} } $$
by an integral like
$$ f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {A(k)e^{(kz-wt) }dk} $$
Does this not change the physical
dimensions of the function ??

Comment: on the first equation you are integrating over a space of functions $A_i$ whereas on the second equation you are integrating over a variable $k$. Those two equations are certainly not equivalent and have completely different meanings.

Comment: So when and how exactly can we replace such a summation by an integration ?

Comment: That summation is already an integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. The dimensions must indeed match.

If you think of $A()$ in the summation as giving the height of a rectangle (units length) then there is an implicit length $\Delta (i) = 1$ to get units of area for the answer. (The exponential factor is a unitless weight.)

In the integral $A(x)$ and $dx$ each have units length.

(Perhaps a physicist or applied mathematician will weigh in with a discussion of Fourier series compared to Fourier integrals.)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see it better, I think there is a typo and the first equation should be

$$ f(z)=\sum_i {A(k_i)e^{(k_i z-wt)} } $$

is that right?

if that is right, then the whole question is just a matter of using $k$ as a discrete of continuous variable. That depends on the interpretation of $k$ on the particular problem you are facing.